# Oracle SQL subqueries to link multiple tables

Tags: oracle, subquery

I have 3 different datasets

Data1:

```
ID  Rank_down
1   
2   
3
```

data2:

```
ID  From    To
1   AB     CD
2   EF     JK
3   PQ  PQ
```

data3:

```
From/To  rank
  AB     1
  CD     2
  EF     3
  JK     5
  PQ     9
```

I need to populate the field rank_down as Y/N based on whether the ID has moved from a higher rank to a lower rank (1 being the lowest).This has to be done in Oracle SQl. I am new to this programming hence finding it difficult to write a subquery.

Can any one help?

Comment: NO time/order is defined for your rank_down.  order is not defined in a table so how do we know how to sort data 3 so we can get the proper ranking?  define some expected results given your sample data to help clairify.  So should ID 1 be rank Y as it went from 1-2 and ID 2 be Y since it went from 3-5?  and ID 3 be null since it didn't move?

Comment: Order is not guaranteed in data3.  How do we know what order to put these in; so that the ranks and from/to go up/down appropriatly for rank_down?

Comment: Then it can't be done.  since order of data in table3 isn't guaranteed we may see CD,2 first then AB,1.  in which case rank_down would be N  or is rank how you define the order? and that AB and CD define Up/down?  and what would PQ be?

Comment: If the movement from PQ to PQ the rank_down would be 'N' so data1.id=data2.id and data2.from!=data2.to & then check the rank

Comment: How is a move from rank 1 to rank 2 a move "down" if in the problem statement you said "1 being the **lowest**"? Why do you expect to be taken seriously if you don't write your problem statement carefully?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select t.*, 
      CASE WHEN 
           ( SELECT "RANK" FROM DATA_3 d
             WHERE d.From_To = t."FROM"
           )
           >
           ( SELECT "RANK" FROM DATA_3 d
             WHERE d.From_To = t."TO"
           )
        THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
        As rank_down 
from data_2 t;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just not following so I'll try some SQL and see if this gets us closer...

Does this select give the desired results in a select fashion?  (I may have the Y/N's inverted)

```
SELECT ID, Case when D3a.Rank < D3b.Rank then 'N' 
                when D3a.Rank > D3b.Rank then 'Y'
                when D3a.Rank = D3b.Rank then 'N'
                end as Rank_down
FROM data2 D2
INNER JOIN data3 D3a
 on D3a.From_To = D2.From
INNER JOIN data3 D3b
 on D3b.From_To = D2.To
```

if so we just need to do an update based on it.

```
UPDATE Data1 d1
INNER JOIN (    SELECT ID, Case when D3A.Rank < D3b.Rank then 'N' 
                    when D3A.Rank > D3B.Rank then 'Y'
                    when D3A.Rank = D3B.Rank then 'N'
                    end as Rank_down
    FROM data2 D2
    INNER JOIN data3 D3a
     on D3a.From_To = D2.From
    INNER JOIN data3 D3b
     on D3B.From_To = D2.To) B
on B.ID = d1.ID 
set d1.Rank_down = B.Rank_Down
```